# Convert Numbers that show as strings in Pandas, while ignoring other Strings that need to be kept the same

Tags: python, pandas

I have data where the dimension is inconsistent between numeric and string formats, and some of the numeric formats even show up as a string.

Unfortunately `astype()` and `to_numeric()` won't work for me here, as you'll see why with the sample data:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'col_a': [1, '1', 2, '2', 'non_numerical'], 'col_b': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['col_a', 'col_b'])
```

I would like to aggregate the data, like this:

```
col_a col_b
1    3
2    7
'non_numerical'    5
```

I'm thinking that I need to write a for loop with an if else statement to check and convert data types, but I'm hoping there's a simpler way with python and/or pandas.

Thanks!

Comment: Please pick a solution that best fit for your use.  Of course, the best fit is based on your criteria (fulfillment of requirement, simplicity, efficiency, etc.)

Comment: Thanks @SeaBean.  I just picked a solution now.  I'm surprised that stackoverflow allowed me to pick a solution, as I thought I remembered another time when I had to wait 24 hours before I was allowed to pick a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by making `col_a` all strings instead of trying to make them numeric. If you wanted to later add values in col_a or something, then of course you wouldn't be able to.

```py
df['col_a2'] = df['col_a'].astype(str)
pd.pivot_table(df,index='col_a2',values='col_b',aggfunc='sum')

col_a2  col_b
1   3
2   7
non_numerical   5
```

If you didn't want to make `col_a2`, just re-write over `col_a` by not putting the 2 there.

Answer (score 2):

`to_numeric` should work with coercing + fillna:

```
out = (df.assign(col_a=pd.to_numeric(df['col_a'],errors='coerce').fillna(df['col_a']))
         .groupby("col_a",as_index=False).sum())
```

---

```
print(out)

           col_a  col_b
0              1      3
1              2      7
2  non_numerical      5
```

Comment: Thanks this is helpful.  I had tried the coercion, but perhaps since I didn't use  `assign` the 'non_numerical' row was dropped.  This here works for me, and the other suggestions about converting to string / rather than numerical, are also good ideas.

Answer (score 1):

You can firstly use [`.assign()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) to create a temporary column of `col_a` with conversion to string type and with the same column name.  Use this new temporary column for [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and aggregation with [`.sum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html), as follows:

```
df.assign(col_a=df['col_a'].astype(str)).groupby('col_a', as_index=False).sum()
```

In this way, you can get the aggregation result without modifying the original contents of `col_a` since we only convert the column to string on the temporary column without touching the original column.

Result:

```
           col_a  col_b
0              1      3
1              2      7
2  non_numerical      5
```